# How can I use loadLayout() more than once in a single method?

Tags: magento

I'm writing a checkout method that needs to get two HTML blocks to be returned via one AJAX call.

Here's what I tried:

```
$this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
$reviewHtml = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->toHtml();

$this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_paymentmethod');
$paymentMethodsHtml = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->toHtml();
```

In this case, both `$reviewHtml` and `$paymentMethodsHtml`, contain `$reviewHtml`.  If I swap the order, it's, of course, reversed.  What's the proper way to load a subsequent layout?

Comment: Ah, well seemed easiest to create a new XML node in the checkout layout XML that contained checkout_onepage_review and checkout_onepage_paymentmethod XML blocks in it.

Answer (score 2):

Hi try to provide an array in your `$this->loadLayout(array('checkout_onepage_review', 'checkout_onepage_paymentmethod'))`